# C# : Proper "if - elseif" formatting

Tags: c#, if-statement

I frequently run into the following problem, I was wondering if there is any better way to deal with it:

```
if (A || B)
{
    //Start stuff if either A or B is true. Then:

    if (A && B)
        //DoSomething
    else if (A && !B)
        //DoSomething
    else if (B && !A)
        //DoSomething
}
```

I'm asking because the if-elseif-elseif eventually looks like a big mess to read through, when the comments are replaced by code. Not even talking about what to do when theres a C involved. Any help is welcome~

Comment: Your outside `if statement` is redundant.

Comment: @George No, it isn’t (because there’s some semantic action happening before the other `if`s).

Comment: Really? “Not constructive”? The closing mafia strikes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't really be answered, but anyway, here are some thoughts:

- Use Polymorphism
- Factor out methods

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, the two last conditions are a bit redundant and can be simplified:

```
if (A && B)
    //DoSomething
else if (A)
    //DoSomething
else if (B)
    //DoSomething
```

Since we already know that both cannot be `true`. Apart from that, I don’t see how this could be simplified much further. Since you are essentially interested in each permutation of cases, you fundamentally need to treat them all.